Should I remove my entire basement window to change partial rotted frame?
After a particulary nasty rain storm, we had some bad water infiltration coming from under the window frame.(yes and no window well - next project!)
There was a poor parging job done and water was sneaking its way up below the bottom of the parging and has begun rotting the frame for quite some time.
It seems the water rot did not penetrate fully as seen from the frame inside and still seems fairly strong.
Is it worth the job to rip out entire window and change the bottom plates? or is there some way to amend from the outside and re-parge the area to stop water infiltration.
Thoughts?



If the rot does not go too far in, then might be able to cut out the cut the rot and replace with new water resistant wood.  If it goes under the window, removing will make the work easier.

For my standards, it doesn't look too far gone. I'd dry it, apply silicone, then replace the mortar.
